# Windows 7 on VMware Workstation 8

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, installation

I'd like to know is there any tutorial how to install Windows 7 on VMware Workstation 8. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This should do: http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/install-windows-7-in-vmware-workstation
The creation process of a VM is similar to older versions, it all starts at "Create a New Virtual Machine".

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the create new Virtual Machine button and mount the windows 7 ISO (or insert the CD). The rest is accepting defaults.